# using grep to get IP and Port out of a banner

Tags: linux, grep, ip, port

I have a list of banners which are at this format:

```
Hostname: []
IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Port: xx
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /login.html
Content-Type: text/html
Device-Access-Level: 255
Content-Length: 3066
Cache-Control: max-age=7200, must-revalidate
```

I have used the following grep statement in order to grab the ip:

```
grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

What do I have to add to the statement in order to grab the port also? (while still getting the IP.).

Thank you for the answers..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `awk`

```
awk '/IP:/ {ip=$2} /Port:/ {print ip,$2}' file
```

When it find line with `IP:` it stores the IP in variable `ip`
When it find port, print `ip` and port number.

---

Example

```
cat file
Hostname: []
IP: 163.248.1.20
Port: 843
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /login.html
Content-Type: text/html
Device-Access-Level: 255
Content-Length: 3066
Cache-Control: max-age=7200, must-revalidat
```

```
awk '/IP:/ {ip=$2} /Port:/ {print ip,$2}' file
163.248.1.20 843
```

Comment: I didn't use because I do not know how.  I will try and use it.!